# How to escape characters in this URL

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
onclick='window.open(" ***  ","List","scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=280");'
```

I want to replace the `***` with this:

```
<%# "~/pages/AttchmentViewer.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ID").ToString() %>
```

but I have problems with the result with the quotation marks:

```
<a runat="server" id="DocTitleLabel" 

onclick='window.open(\"<%# "~/pages/AttchmentViewer.aspx?ID=" + 
Eval("ID").ToString()  %>" \", "List", "scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=280");'>

      <%# Eval("DocTitle") %> 
</a>
```

Any help!!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (tested), but as I told you the ~ must be omitted you just need to give relative path,

onclick='<%# "window.open(\"~/pages/AttchmentViewer.aspx?ID=" + Eval("Id").ToString() + "\", \"List\",\"scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=280\");" %>'

Answer (score 1):

You're escaping the wrong quotation marks, the ones inside the URL need to be escaped not the ones around it.. Also encoding the query-string is a good idea.

So try `onclick='window.open("<%# \"~/pages/AttchmentViewer...` instead of `onclick='window.open(\"<%# "~/pages/AttchmentViewer...`. (same applies for the closing marks)

Although I wonder what the server-tags (<% %>) will do ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for the server-tags, they're for get the `Eval("ID")` and concatenate it with the target page's URL

Comment: Then you could write the start-tag right before Eval("ID") instead of surrounding the whole URL, couldn't you? That way you wouldn't even need to concatenate anything as the code inside the server-tags would just replace the ID.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to [urlencode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) the string